# iCal subscription link doesn't sync [Outlook365 Outlook and .net core app]

Tags: .net, outlook, webcal

I noticed strange behavior.
Connection to the calendar in outlook365 generally works. It adds all my events.
But when I try to edit some event in my .net core application, and try to sync with Office365 Outlook nothing happens.

I tried webcal:// as well as webcals:// links.

Everything works, but sync process seems it doesn't.
Any hints what could be wrong?